# C++ compile error with iostream

Tags: c++, inheritance, iostream

I am using fstream and got some error.

Here is what I have:

```
class CLog
{
    void printOn(std::ostream& dbg) const;
}

void operator>>(const CLog& s, std::ofstream& dbg)
{
    s.printOn(dbg);
}
```

But when I compile I got the following error:

```
error C2664: 'printOn' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
'class std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >' to 
'class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>  > &' 
A reference that is not to 'const' cannot be bound to a non-lvalue
```

I thought that ofstream inherit from ostream so why it is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: Arggg! found out a missing `#include <fstream>`. What a stupid output from the compiler. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make printOn public and include fstream  header :).

```
#include <fstream>
class CLog
{
public:
    void printOn(std::ostream& dbg) const
    {

    }
};

std::ofstream & operator<<( std::ofstream& dbg, const CLog& s)
{
    s.printOn(dbg);
}
```

Comment: printOn was public fstream was missing thanks :). But why is the compiler output so useless in this situation.

Comment: Also worth noting that you swapped the order of the parameters in operator>>, important for the extraction operator that the stream be on the left hand side. If you actually meant to it to be a operator<<, then the order of parameters is correct, as another answer pointed out

Answer (score 6):

More correct declaration of output operator is following:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& dbg, const CLog& s)
{
    s.printOn(dbg);
    return dbg;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be operator >>

Comment: And you may declare it as a friend operation in CLog class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest posting *complete* code allowing to reproduce the problem.  I've none with:

```
#include <fstream>

class CLog
{
public:
    void printOn(std::ostream& dbg) const;
};

void operator>>(const CLog& s, std::ofstream& dbg)
{
    s.printOn(dbg);
}
```